# EditText with edit mode

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need an editable text area that functions very similarly to the text area in the Google Drive app on Android. Does anyone know how to do what the Google Drive text area is doing?

Features:

- View mode that doesn't bring up the keyboard, but shows a cursor
- The cursor displays the edit action when you move it around
- Edit mode can also be triggered by the edit action in the ActionBar
- Edit mode brings up something like the done/discard pattern with a list of formatting actions
- Edit mode is exited by pressing "Done"

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm working on something currently that is similar to this.

Define an xml layout for the editing options, ie. done, undo, redo, indent and formatting. Then inflate this view using a fragment class. I implemented an interior interface to allow my main activity to listen to click events from the fragment.

```
package com.aesop.systems.top_bar;

import com.aesop.systems.cerulean.R;
import com.aesop.systems.utils.Frag;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TopBarEditor extends Frag implements OnClickListener {

private LinearLayout save;
private ImageView undo, redo, indent, outdent, code_in;

private EditorTopBarListener listen;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup con, Bundle bundy) {
    root = inf.inflate(R.layout.top_bar_editor, con, false);
    loadContent();
    return root;
}

@Override
public void loadContent() {
    save = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);

    undo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.undo);
    undo.setOnClickListener(this);
    redo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redo);
    redo.setOnClickListener(this);
    indent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.indent);
    indent.setOnClickListener(this);
    outdent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.outdent);
    outdent.setOnClickListener(this);
    code_in = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.code_in);
    code_in.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View cl) {
    if(listen != null)
    {
        if(save == cl)
        {
            listen.onSave();
        }
        else if(undo == cl)
        {
            listen.onUndo();
        }
        else if(redo == cl)
        {
            listen.onRedo();
        }
        else if(outdent == cl)
        {
            listen.onOutdent();
        }
        else if(indent == cl)
        {
            listen.onIndent();
        }
        else if(code_in == cl)
        {
            listen.onCodeIn();
        }
    }
}

public interface EditorTopBarListener
{
    public void onSave();
    public void onUndo();
    public void onRedo();
    public void onIndent();
    public void onOutdent();
    public void onCodeIn();
}

public void addEditorTopBarListener(EditorTopBarListener list) { listen = list; }
```

}

The above class was extended from Frag; a class I made to mimic a normal custom view. The code for it is as follows. View root is needed to find the views easily and is protected so that extended classes can still reference it. For this reason it is essential to define it when the fragment is inflated. i.e root = inf.inflate(R.layout.top_bar_editor, con, false);

```
public abstract class Frag extends Fragment {

    protected View root;

    public View findViewById(int id)
    {
        return root.findViewById(id);
    }

    public abstract void loadContent();

}
```

In your main activity add a OnFocusChangedListener to the EditText.

```
editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) toggleEditorBar();
            else toggleDefaultBar();
        }
    });
```

Then handle the operations when the EditText focus has changed into editing mode by toggling the editor specific fragment. If it loses focus return to the default bar. In my instance the 'holder' for the fragments is a LinearLayout with the id R.id.topbar. To toggle use a convenience method such as.

```
public void toggleDefaultBar()
{
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.top_bar, default_bar).commit();
}

public void toggleEditorBar()
{
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.top_bar, editor_bar).commit();
}
```

The toggling and onFocusChangedListener should be implemented in your main activity and also should implement the custom interface if you choose to make one. If you do not, then upon returning the root view from the fragment you must manually add onClickListeners for each within the main Activity class. A small example I have not tried yet could be done like. . .

```
   TopBarEditor edit = new TopBarEditor(Activity.this);

   ImageView undo = (ImageView) edit.findViewById(R.id.undo);
   undo.setOnClickListener(this);   // if the activity implements a listener
```

Doing so will cause readability issues further down the line though and its easier, I've found to implement a custom interface so that you know explicitly what is being called from the implemented interface methods.

Hope I helped and I apologize for the length, but this won't be a quick process to implement and I think more is better for this type of question.

-Chris